# Can I cast a value in a properties file using SpringBoot configuration?

Tags: class, spring-boot, casting, properties, configuration

Is it possible to cast a configuration property which is read by SpringBoot from a properties file into a specific class? 
For instance, having a property

```
myClass = xx.abc.MyClass
```

In my configuration class I want to have something like:

```
private Class myClass = xx.abc.MyClass.class;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding a custom converter. [Using Type Converters With Spring MVC](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-type-converters-with-spring-mvc/) helped me to find the solution:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class StringToClassConverter implements Converter<String, java.lang.Class> {
    @Override
    public Class convert(final String source) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(source);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
            // Handle exception properly however you want to...
            cnfEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You have your SpringBoot main class let extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and implement and implement the register method from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToClassConverter());
}
```

**Update:**

SpringBoot has its own capabilities and it seems top be better to achieve the goal this way:

1. Annotate the Converter with 
   @Component and 
     @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding

OR

2. Use @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppProperties.class) along with @SpringBootApplication

@see 
[Spring Boot - Custom Type Conversion with @ConfigurationProperties](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/custom-configuration-properties-binding.html) 

and 
[Spring Boot - Type safe properties binding with @ConfigurationProperties](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/configuration-properties.html)

That's it! :-)

It would be nice that Spring would provide such basic converters out of the box.